# Want to get all after 2nd encounter of special character

Tags: sql, oracle

Here O am trying to get `abc999998_-1` from the below string.

`MG-999998-abc999998_-1`

Everything after the second occurrence of the special character (Hyphen).
Can someone please help me with getting this string?

Thanks

Tried below, but it is giving till last hyphen, but I want everything after the 2nd hyphen.

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
l_temp_val varchar2(100) := 'MG-999998-abc999998_-1';
l_invoice_num varchar2(100);
begin
select DECODE(substr(substr(l_temp_val,3),1,1),'-',
            regexp_substr(l_temp_val,'[^-]+',1,3),
            regexp_substr(l_temp_val,'[^-]+',1,2) ) 
    into l_invoice_num  from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(l_invoice_num);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with [REGEXP_INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions162.htm#SQLRF06300) function.

Try this one:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
l_temp_val varchar2(100) := 'MG-999998-abc999998_-1';
l_invoice_num integer;
begin
select REGEXP_INSTR(l_temp_val, '-', 1, 2)
    into l_invoice_num  from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(substr(l_temp_val, l_invoice_num+1));
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `INSTR( value, '-', 1, 2 )` to find the index of the second occurrence of the hyphen character starting from the first character of the string; then if its non-zero a match has been found and you can get the substring starting from the following index.

You also don't need to use a `SELECT` statement.

```sql
declare
  l_temp_val varchar2(100) := 'MG-999998-abc999998_-1';
  l_invoice_num varchar2(100);
begin
  l_invoice_num := CASE
                   WHEN INSTR( l_temp_val, '-', 1, 2 ) > 0
                   THEN SUBSTR( l_temp_val, INSTR( l_temp_val, '-', 1, 2 ) + 1 )
                   END;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_invoice_num);
end;
/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> abc999998_-1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bc3b07a895a3d5b5c1880a32fbcc4b15)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace the first group of characters, hyphen, second group of characters, and hyphen with Nothing as following

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_REPLACE('MG-999998-abc999998_-1', '^[^-]+-[^-]+-', ' ')
  3  FROM
  4      DUAL;

REGEXP_REPLAC
-------------
 abc999998_-1

SQL>
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_REPLACE('MG-999998-second test-abc999998_-1', '^[^-]+-[^-]+-', ' ')
  3  FROM
  4      DUAL;

REGEXP_REPLACE('MG-999998
-------------------------
 second test-abc999998_-1

SQL>
```

Cheers!!